# Encoded url output in browser! Is it http_referer or phpbb issue?

Tags: php, phpbb3, http-referer

I integrated phpbb login into my website. 
Steps: it goes to the login.php script to process data and come back to the referer page. 
Note: this page (referer) has something like **page.php?var1=x&var2=y**
After login process it returns as **page.php?var1=x&ampvar2=y** which creates an error in the browser. 
I am not allowed (by phpbb) to use directly the $_server[http_referer].
Below you can see the code from login.php. 
**I also echo the data, as you can see, and it's ok!**

```
$username=addslashes(strip_tags(strtolower(($_REQUEST['username']))));
$password=addslashes(strip_tags($_REQUEST['password']));

define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '../../forum/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/bbcode.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);
$te=$request->variable('HTTP_REFERER', '', false, \phpbb\request\request_interface::SERVER);
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();

$result = $auth->login($username, $password, '', 1, 0);
print_r($result);
if($user->data['is_registered'])
        {
    echo '<br>//User is already logged in';
    }
else
{                    
if ($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS)
{
    echo '<br>//User was successfully logged into phpBB';
}
else
{
    echo '<br>//Users login failed';
}
}
//header('Location:'$te);
echo "location:..".$request->variable('HTTP_REFERER', '', false, \phpbb\request\request_interface::SERVER);
```

Comment: Hello, Is it really that complicated or I wasn't clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpBBs `$request` class is escaping your `HTTP_REFERER` as part of its built in sanitisation. To temporarily enable globals you can use `$request->enable_super_globals();` but you will have to do your own checks/sanitisation to make sure the values are safe. Once you have your value you can disable globals again with `$request->disable_super_globals();`

Alternatively, you could use `str_replace` to get your ampersand character back which is safer than the above as the class will still check and sanitise for you...

`$te = str_replace('&amp','&',$request->variable('HTTP_REFERER', '', false, \phpbb\request\request_interface::SERVER));`

Comment: Thank you. Most probably this is it. But then why it looks ok if I echo $te as I mentioned above?

Comment: Thank you again! Str_replace works great!...maybe it was the browser that displayed & instead of &amp to confuse me.

Comment: That will be your browser interpreting the encoded character. If you view the source in your browser it will still be `&amp`.